# http-server -p 8080 error "No such file or directory"

Tags: node.js, npm, httpserver

I wanted to start a node js http server on my Linux machine for a specific directory which will be accessed by my windows laptop.

After I ran this command
`npm install http-server -g`
I tried to start server on current directory by giving command `http-server -p 8080`.

But it gives message

> : No such file or directory

Can somebody let me know where I am doing error?

Comment: Is that the complete error you get?

Comment: Yes. That's all

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have the `node` executable, but the `nodejs` executable.

You can confirm this by trying to run the command `node`, which should fail, and command `nodejs` which should start the node interpreter.

**Option 1:**

Create a symlink to `nodejs` binary as follows and try again.

```
sudo ln -s "$(which nodejs)" /usr/bin/node
```

**Option 2:**

Do a `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

Comment: It is complete reverse of what you assume.
Trying nodejs is failed and node is starting interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the path

```
http-server [path] [options]
```

Try this:

```
http-server ./ -p 8080
```

Comment: can you give the node version on which you are running??  `node -v`